# Creating a view for a many-to-many with additional properties

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through, formtastic

I have a many-to-many relationship between projects and stages, I'm trying to build a form that will allow a user to check off stages in a project and make any comments on that stage.

This is roughly what the model looks like:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :project_stages
  has_many :stages, :through => :project_stages
end

class Stage < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :project_stages
  has_many :projects, :through => :project_stages
end

class ProjectStage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :stage
end
```

My first view implementation just used Formtastic to display a list of checkboxes for each project, to allow the user to check each stage as it was completed.

Unfortunately the model has now become slightly more complex with a completion_date and completion_comment for each project_stage.

I'm not sure how to rewrite the view so that I can display a checkbox for each stage, along with a completion_date and completion_comment field for that stage.

I also think I need to fix the update method so that any ids that get unchecked, that relationship gets destroyed?

I have had a look through the Formtastic doco, along with the usual google searches, and I can't find a pattern for achieving what I'm trying to do.

Any pointers in the right direction would be very much appreciated please.

Thanks in advance for any ansers you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Making a great many to many user experience (UX) is tricky. Especially when the relationship has its own properties as it does in your case (completion_date and completion_comment).

I suggest using an jQuery form with Ajax to create/update/delete the relationships for a given model instance.

This [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields) shows how to add a binary-style (it's either there or not) many to many relationship. But when the relationship has attributes, you need a way to "open" the relationship to change the attributes.

You also have to decide how the relationships display. Again, there are many choices.

Eg, you can open a jQuery [dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) when the user clicks on the relationship name. The dialog would enable updates and deletion of the relationship.